# YouTube In WebVIew - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, youtube

This is very strange to me...

I have a simple WebView that loads and interacts with the user exactly like safari mobile (iPhone). Now when you visit m.youtube.com in safari, the url changes when you click on a link to something like this...

```
http://m.youtube.com/watch?gl=US&hl=en&client=mv-google&v=HX6SyoZ5kw8
```

The problem with this is I don't think that url is being used in my webview... What do I mean? The following code is used to load a url every time the user try's to click on a link, and it works, but I have a problem with Youtube...

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSURL *url = request.URL;
NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;
NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
VideoURLTextBox.text = urlString;
return YES;
}
```

When I first start up the webview it loads m.youtube.com and NSLogs() it into my console, but when I decide to click on a video it fails to NSLog() therefore I don't think a new url is being loaded, but when you load m.youtube.com in safari and click on a video you load a url like above, so why does this not NSLog() in my iPhone application?

Comment: Do you mean this method isn't being called, therefore you do not see your `NSLog`? If so, you are probably missing the `UIWebView` delegate.

Comment: No because the method does get called at the beginning when I first load the webview...

Comment: Are you using `+ (id)requestWithURL:(NSURL *)theURL` for every URL you want to access? How are you handling that? If you could post the code that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your probably seeing is that the youtube video is running javascript to play the video, you'd have to intercept the javascript callbacks to see that.  Here's a link to the youtube video player api, detailing the callbacks, https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#SubscribingEvents

If you just want to embed a youtube video in an iOS application then use this.

Using the mobile YouTube site isn't great, I had lots of problems with it in the past and ended up making a UIWebView category.  I came across your question and decided to throw it on github :-)

https://github.com/enigmaticflare/UIWebView-YouTube--iOS-Category--ARC-compliant-code

UIWebView+YouTube iOS category to simplify loading youtube videos.

Instructions

1) Add these files to your project

```
UIWebView+YouTube.h
UIWebView+YouTube.m
```

2) Initiate UIWebView for example

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView *webView;
@synthesize webView = _webView

_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,212,172];
//set the X,Y origin of CGRect to where you want the webView to appear.

_webView.delegate = self;
[_webView loadYouTubeVideoID:@"gR8dO7Cln6M"];
[self.view addSubView:_webView];
```

Good luck, hope this is what your looking for :)

Adam

Answer (score 0):

m.youtube.com is one giant java web app, delegate methods won't get called, presumably because any loading is written directly to the DOM in the UIWebView.  Ran into this problem at work, not sure of the fix but there may be a way to inject the source with a JS click handler.